# Why is $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left\lfloor\frac{\sin|x|}{x}\right\rfloor= 0\,?$

Tags: limits

> Problem: Check $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left\lfloor\frac{\sin|x|}{x}\right\rfloor$$

Now, what the book does is this:

> $$\textrm{RHL} \implies\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left\lfloor\frac{\sin|x|}{x}\right\rfloor = \lim_{h\to 0} \left\lfloor\frac{\sin|0 +h|}{0+h}\right\rfloor$$
>
> We know, $\dfrac{\sin h}{h}\to 1$ as $h\to 0$ **but less than 1**
>
> $$\therefore \textrm{RHL}= 0$$
>
> Again, $$\textrm{LHL}\implies \lim_{h\to 0} \left\lfloor\frac{\sin|0 -h|}{0-h}\right\rfloor$$
>
> We know $\dfrac{\sin h}{-h}\to -1$ as $h\to 0$ **but greater than -1**
>
> $$\therefore \textrm{LHL}= -1$$

I really couldn't conceive what the author meant by those bold phrases.

Comment: Could the second bold phrase be "but greater than -1" Notice the minus... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author is saying is that, when $h>0$, $$\frac{\sin h}h<1,\ \ \ \text{ so } \left\lfloor\frac{\sin h}h\right\rfloor=0.$$

In the second part he says that, if you approach from the left, 
$$\frac{\sin h}{-h}>-1,\ \ \ \text{ so } \left\lfloor\frac{\sin h}h\right\rfloor=-1.$$

Comment: And in other words.. it means that  $\frac{\sin h}{-h}$ approaches  $-1$  when $h-->0$ from the right side, and $\frac{\sin h}{h}$  approaches  $1$  when $h-->0$ from the left side.